# How to change location of syslog file from /var/log to /opt/log in linux?

Tags: linux, logging, ubuntu-14.04, syslog, rsyslog

I want to log my all logs in a log file present in /opt/log folder.
For this, I have changed the path to /opt/log in syslog.conf file and then restarted the log service but still, it is not working.

Comment: share your syslog.conf file ?

Comment: I am not able to copy the whole code but I have done the require thing 

:auth,authpriv.*                 /var/log/auth.log
*.*;auth,authpriv.none          -/opt/log/syslog1.log